# Getting all the Carriers in dropdown menu

Tags: magento-1.7, shipment, shipment-tracking

How do we get all the carriers available in Magento drop down menu? I want the carriers drop-down menu in user dashboard (not is Superadmin) so user can select and add the tracking no. I have gone through many post but unable to get the particular method.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public function getAllShippingMethods()
{
    $methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
            $options = array();

            foreach($methods as $_code => $_method)
            {
                if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_code/title"))
                    $_title = $_code;
                $options[] = array('value' => $_code, 'label' => $_title . " ($_code)");
            }

    return $options; // This array will have all the active shipping methods
}
```

Comment: This will get you only the active carriers. Each carrier can have multiple shipping methods, that can be identified only based on a quote object. But still..+1

Comment: @Su123 .. Thanks for your answer. I have some doubts. I have checked in superadmin that carriers are showing only DHL, UPS , USPS, Custome Values and DHL deprecated while adding tracking number. In your given function it is also showing the Free Shipping (freeshipping), Flat Rate (flatrate)". I am confused like is this also carriers or methods which is showing the return array...

Comment: @Marius ... What is the quote object in magento... I am sorry i am new in programming.

Comment: The quote is the order before pressing place order. So...the cart.